# Abstract Methods when Implementing Node

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a new type of Pane in JavaFX. When extending Node I am forced to implement four abstract methods that are not in the Javadocs for Node. Can anyone help me understand what these are and why they are not covered in the Javadoc?

```
protected NGNode impl_createPeer() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public BaseBounds impl_computeGeomBounds(BaseBounds bounds, BaseTransform tx) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
protected boolean impl_computeContains(double localX, double localY) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public Object impl_processMXNode(MXNodeAlgorithm alg, MXNodeAlgorithmContext ctx) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Comment: Those method names do not comply to java naming conventions. Therefore I assume that it is your imternal extention of Node you inherit them from.

Comment: If you want to create a new `Pane`, extend `Pane`, not node directly. Or at least `Region`. Those methods are deprecated anyways which means it's probably not a good idea to implement them yourself. However the middle 2 seem to be responsible for the size computation and the check, if a certain point is contained in the `Node` The documentation expicitly states that every single one them will be removed in javafx 9 and tells you to treat all of them as private. So better keep your hands off those methods.

Comment: All I did was say "extends Node" can you please elaborate on 'internal extention' ?

Comment: Your right. Great thanks fabian!

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDE you can click the up arrow by the line count to look at the decompiled code. There you will see that there is a comment that states that it is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version. I'm not sure how you could see the decompiled codes in other IDE's but it is obvious that what ever the developers intended these methods to be used for is not ready. It's best to just ignore them for now.